# mysql error using variable as table name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Why I'm getting this error?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectrecords`(tablename varchar(50))
begin
set @table_name=tablename;
set @sql_text=concat('Select * from @table_name');
prepare statement from @sql_text;
execute statement;
deallocate prepare statement;
end
```

Error:

```
....to use near '@table_name' at line 1
```

My code is correct but I don't understand why....

Comment: I don't think you can use variables for table names in dynamic sql. In Oracle you sure can't at all. I think you have to concatenate, see JW's answer

Comment: @Sebas: What if I am using "delete frrom....where" , JW's answer is still acceptable?

Comment: yes, I think he pretty much answered all your questions.

Comment: I'm getting error with this: "set @sql_text = concat('Delete  from ', tablename, 'WHERE id = pid');" "pid int"--> is included in parameter..Any help?

Comment: add a space before WHERE

Comment: i really had an error in Where clause part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27117/discussion-between-handy-manny-and-sebas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `selectrecords`(tablename varchar(50))
begin
    set @sql_text = concat('Select * from ', tablename);
    prepare statement from @sql_text;
    execute statement;
    deallocate prepare statement;
end
```

even in *dynamic* sql, you cannot parameterized table names as well as column names so your only choice is to concatenate in with the string. Only values can be place in a place holder.

- [MySQL PREPARE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `selectrecords`(tablename varchar(50))
begin
    set @val = idnumber;
    set @sql_text = concat('Select * from ', tablename, ' WHERE id = ?');
    prepare statement from @sql_text;
    execute statement USING @val;
    deallocate prepare statement;
end
```

Comment: What if I want to include the id in parameter? Let us say I want to query like this "Delete from tablename where id =idnumber" ?

Comment: `SET @sql = 'Delete from tablename where id = ?'` you can place the value of `idnumber` in a placeholder.

Comment: I mean I am still using that code above but this time with where clause . How to concat including where ?

Comment: Thanks! You are really a geek :)

Comment: One more thing, I want to include 'id int' in my parameter and delete a record in my database, is this right? "SET @sql=concat('Delete from', tablename,' Where id=pid');

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27110/discussion-between-handy-manny-and-j-w)

Comment: What if I want to add this statement "ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;" How should i call this one in prepared statement?

Comment: In the second query (UPDATE 1), shouldn't `idnumber` be a second parameter of the procedure? Or is it taken from the global vars somehow?